# Mysqli Query Result Different When Called from PHP than When Called from Mysql Shell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have searched for answers on this, but can't find anything online.

I am having trouble with a query which gives the correct result set when run from the mysql shell on the computer, but a different one when run from mysqli in the PHP script.

The query is:

```
SELECT q.pos, q.event_ID, e.name FROM (SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @event_ID=e_ID THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS pos, @event_ID:=e_ID as event_ID, u_ID from event_queue ORDER BY e_ID, dateadded) AS q INNER JOIN event AS e ON q.event_ID = ID WHERE q.u_ID=11;
```

If this is called from mysqli then I get the incorrect position value (q.pos) of 1, if run from the mysql shell then I get the correct value of 4. I think it is because it is using a variable in the mysql code, but I can't find anything online which describes this issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was just to remove the semi colon from the end of the first SQL query.

I had:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon,"SET @row_number=0;");
```

I changed it to:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon,"SET @row_number=0");
```

and it worked. I also needed to set the @event_ID variable in another mysqli query.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, wouldn't have been able to get there without help from the community though so I feel a bit bad accepting my own solution.

Comment: We appreciate that but what is more important for the community is to have working answers accepted so they are easier to find for the next person. When you get enough rep you'll be able to upvote answers that help you on your way.